# Wpf Prism give style to each items of a ItemControl (Views in a Region)

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a `WPF` `Prism` project and it has a `Region` base on `ItemControl`:

```
<ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion" >
```

In this `ItemControl` i see some of my `Views` verticaly well but i want give a style to each `Item` of `ItemControl` (each `View`).

> All of items (views) must have same style (for example: background
>   color, padding, margin, border and...)

I want something like this (for example):

[image]

I used a simple style and code like this:

```
<ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion"  Background="#765e4d" Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" Padding="10" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

Its Error:

> A style intended for type 'ItemsControl' cannot be applied to type
>   'View1'

Also i tested this codes:

```
<ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion"  Background="#765e4d" Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" Padding="10" Margin="10" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But the result is like when i write:

```
<ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion" >
```

[image]

- Why? What is my mistake?
- How can i do this?

---

**Edit1:**

I used `<ItemsPresenter/>`  instead of `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>`

Result: without any change

---

**Edit2:**

I write this style for ItemContainerStyle property of the ItemsControl and it works **if** i remove `ControlTemplate` part from it.

**Now the question is which kind of `Presenter` or `Xaml Tag` i should use inside the following `ControlTemplate` to my `Views` (`UserControls`) be shown.**

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                     ??????????????????????????
                    <!-- The following ContentPresenter not working and the Items dose not show -->
                    <ContentPresenter/> 
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You have for example 3 items in your ItemsCollection and you want to have one style per item instead of one style for all items?

Comment: @mDC yes but one style for all items. I think each View of the Region shows in an Item in ItemsControl and i want apply a style on each Item. All of items (views) must have same style.

Comment: Could you provide a picture what the result actually is? That would help me understand :)

Comment: @mDC, i added a picture of my Shell. you can see **no one of the views** has any style like border or padding or margin....

Comment: The `ItemContainerStyle` applies to the `<ContentPresenter>` item that wraps each item in your ItemsControl. I'm not positive, but I didn't think the `ContentPresenter` has a `Control.Template` property. Try setting the `ContentTemplate` property instead.

Comment: @Rachel, your Comment was very good. I like your answers in stackoverflow always. :) It works now... May you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @RAM Sure, I actually just finished writing it as an answer :) I saw your Edit #2 and realized that was probably where you were going wrong. I wasn't really sure if Prism regions had anything to do with it as I haven't worked with them a lot, so didn't post an answer at first since I didn't know if they were part of the problem.

Comment: @Rachel yes, my mistake was about using `Template` instead of  `ContentTemplate`. Usually each `View` in prism is a `UserControl` and it inherit from `ContentControl`, then i was focusing on `ContentPresenter` but my mistake was in a higher level and you said it. Good luck Rachel.

Comment: @RAM care to share a working example? I keep hitting `StackOverflowException` when using `ItemsControl` and setting `ContentTemplate` in `ItemContainerStyle`. `ListView` with `Template` for `ListViewItem` works fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ContentTemplate` property of the style, not `Control.Template` or `Template`

An ItemsControl gets rendered like this :

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsPanel>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <ItemTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter>

        <ContentPresenter>
            <ItemTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter>

        <ContentPresenter>
            <ItemTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemContainerStyle` applies to the `ContentPresenter` object that wraps each item in this XAML tree, and I don't believe a `ContentPresenter` has either a `Control.Template` or a `Template` property.

When changing how a `ContentPresenter` is displayed you should overwrite the `ContentTemplate` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in my test application:

```
<ItemsControl Background="#FF85664F" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" Padding="10"
                    Margin="5, 5, 5, 0" BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFC3BF8F">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <system:String>ItemsControl Item #1</system:String>
    <system:String>ItemsControl Item #2</system:String>
    <system:String>ItemsControl Item #3</system:String>
    <system:String>ItemsControl Item #4</system:String>
    <system:String>ItemsControl Item #5</system:String>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Yes it works well but my question is a **Prism** project in WPF. When you add `prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion"` to it and move your project to prism framework it will not working with `View` items

Comment: you inserted items manually in your sample and your items type are string and string type is different with prism view type then these are different yet. your items are NOT view!

Comment: @RAM Exactly, I guess one must reference the *View-Models* in a *ContentControl* and hope that *Prism* will attach the respective *View*. However *Prism* normally performs these associations in the other way round.