# Reduce repetitions with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have this code snipper

```
DockPanel Margin="3" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
<Label
    Content="Port #1" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
<ComboBox     
    x:Name="Port1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PortList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Port1Selected}">                             
</ComboBox>
</DockPanel>

<DockPanel  Margin="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
<Label
    Content="Port #2" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
<ComboBox                                 
   ItemsSource="{Binding PortList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Port2Selected}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

as you can see there are two `DockPanels` which are basically the same besides their `SelectedItem` property.

at the moment I have 8 those which I duplicated, but it seems like too much copy and paste and prone to errors, and in the future, I might have more port, so I will need to create a new  `DockPanel`.

or even have more complex control that I will need to "duplicate".

I was trying to make custom control contains `<DockPanel> /// </DockPanel >` part, but i don't know to achieve the same functionality and having the same bindings

my question is, how can i achieve this without reputations.

i was looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405138/wpf-prism-give-style-to-each-items-of-a-itemcontrol-views-in-a-region)  and here [prism-example](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/23-RegionMemberLifetime) for some ideas

**UPDATE**

My item controller

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PortList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Margin="3">
                <Label
                    Content="{Binding PortName}" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                     <ComboBox                                 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding PortList}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

my port model

```
    public class PortModel : BindableBase
    {
        public string  PortName { get; set; }
        public List<string> PortList { get; set; }
       // public string SelectedPort { get; set; }

        private string _selectedPort;
        public string SelectedPort
        {
            get { return _selectedPort; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedPort, value); }
        }
    }
```

and my main list in in the view model
#region List Properties

```
    private ObservableCollection<PortModel> portsList;
    public ObservableCollection<PortModel> PortList
    {
        get { return portsList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref portsList, value); }
    }
```

and adding items to the list

```
private void LoadSerialPorts()
{
    portsList.Clear();            

    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.NUMBER_OF_COMS; i++)
    {
        PortList.Add(new PortModel
        {
            PortList = serialPortHandler.GetSerialPortPort().ToList(),
            PortName = $"Port #{i}",
        });
        
    }
   
}
```

**But now the selected port does not fire**

Comment: Create another item class which has a `PortList` and a `SelectedPort` property - where PortList returns the same list for all items. Then put the DockPanel in a DataTemplate for that item class, preferrably as the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl.

Comment: @Clemens should the other class have 1 `SelectedPort` property or as many as i need?

Comment: One SelectedPort property, so that you could write `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}"`

Comment: so how can get a specific `SelectedPort` after ?

Comment: From the SelectedPort property of the respective item.

Comment: @Clemens thanks you very much, i updated my answer, but now the selected port does not fire

Comment: No idea why it does not fire. As a note, you should not be using different collections for the PortList property of multipe PortModel instances. Pass the same instance to all PortModels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224919/discussion-between-styx-and-clemens).

Comment: Your main view model may need to attach a PropertyChanged event handler for the SelectedPort property of the PortModel items.